# Platforms are gradually being spawned further and further away in the Z-axis in a 2D Endless runner game, until they spawn behind the camera

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, platformer, spawning

I am creating a 2D endless runner game, where new platforms get spawned when the player reaches a certain distance to the last platform spawned. The issue that I found was that after the player reaches the 7th spawned platform, the new next spawned platforms appear invisible, although the player can still jump on them and collides normally. For testing purposes I removed the code where the platforms get spawned depending on the player's position, by spawning a definite amount of platforms one after each other, but for some reason after the 7th spawned platform, the next platforms are still invisible.

Here is the code I am using to spawn the platforms:

```
public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour {
    
    [SerializeField] private Transform levelPart_Start;
    [SerializeField] private Transform levelPart_1;

    
    private Vector3 lastEndPosition;

    private void Awake(){
        lastEndPosition = levelPart_Start.Find("EndPosition").position;

        int startingSpawnLevelParts = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < startingSpawnLevelParts; i++){
            SpawnLevelPart();
        }  
    }
   
    private void SpawnLevelPart() {
        Transform lastLevelPartTransform = SpawnLevelPart(lastEndPosition);
        lastEndPosition = lastLevelPartTransform.Find("EndPosition").position;
    }

    private Transform SpawnLevelPart(Vector3 spawnPosition) {
        Transform levelPartTransform = Instantiate(levelPart_1, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        return levelPartTransform;
    }
}
```

Basically, I have set an point at the end of one of the already spawned platforms on the scene, and the code spawns the next platform dependant on that point, then creates another point at the end of the newly spawned platform and so on.

Any idea why the spawned platforms still appear invisible after the 7th spawned platform? Thanks!

Edit:

Here are two screenshots, one showing the last visible platform, and the other showing the first invisible platform, each selected in the inspector.

[image: Last Visible Platform]

[image: First Invisible Platform]

Edit 2:

As mentioned in the edited question title, the platforms are spawned further away in the Z axis from the EndPosition, and the next EndPosition is being spawned further away from the last EndPosition, which this causes the platforms to gradually get closer to the camera until they start spawning on the other side of it, making them invisible.

This is a screenshot showing the scene in 3D View:

[image: 3D View]

Comment: Can you show us one of these invisible platforms selected in the Inspector, so we can see the configuration of its rendering-related components?

Comment: Try going into 3D view, and looking at how your platforms stack front-to-back along the z-axis, relative to your camera. My best guess is that the platforms are ending up on the wrong side of the camera to be seen.

Comment: Thanks! You are correct, the problem is that gradually, the platforms are moving closer and closer to the camera (in the z direction) until they spawn on the other side, which is why they become invisible. First of all, the first EndPosition was not on the same z position as the platforms, which when I fixed that, I can go further then 8 platforms. But for some reason, my code is 

A. Spawning the platforms further away from the EndPosition in the z axis.

B. Spawning the EndPositions further from the last EndPosition in the z axis too.

Any reason to why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Want to edit your question to show the problem in more detail, now that you've isolated it?